# how to mock a method belonging to JPA libraries

Tags: java, jpa, junit, mockito

I would like to mock the make a JUnit test of the following method toXml:

```
void toXml(Object obj){
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
            try{
                JAXBContext ctx = getContext(obj.getClass());
                Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
                marshaller.setAttachmentMarshaller(new AttachmentMarshallerImpl());
                out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                marshaller.marshal( obj, out );
            }catch( JAXBException e ){
                throw new RuntimeException("Problem in parsing", e);
            }
        }
```

I have tried the following:

```
@Test
public void testToXml() throws Exception {

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    SystemPointDto systemPointDto = new SystemPointDto();
    verify((marshaller), atLeast(1)).marshal(systemPointDto, out);
}
```

However I am getting a NullPointerException when I run the test. I am a newbie in testing probably the answer is very easy. Could you please advice? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The mocking code as asked in the comments is:

```
@Mock
AttachmentMarshallerImpl attachmentMarshaller;

@InjectMocks
Marshaller marshaller;
```

And this is the stack trace:

```
initMocks(TestingIfTheMarshalGetsCalledWithoutExceptionTest.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: the type 'Marshaller' is an interface.
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Where are you mocking the marshaller?  What is the stack trace?

Comment: Could you post the mocking code?

Comment: @geoand the mocking code you asked is posted.

Comment: Are you using @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) on your test or perhaps are you using MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)? If you are not using any of these, the annotations have no effect

Comment: Also, it seems to me that you are actually testing the Marshaller, not the testToXml method

Comment: @geoand yes I am using initMocks(this), however still getting an error message that I am using an interface and I should use the implementation, but I don't know which implementation Jboss uses. Is there any way to mock an interface with automatically inject an instance?

Comment: @geoand PS: I just need to test that marshaller.marshal(obj,out) gets called without exception.

Comment: @Rollerball Could you please post the stack trace?

Comment: @geoand Did it, it's normal I think that it complains being Marshaller an interface.

Comment: Try adding the @Mock annotation to Marshaller as well. The way it is now, it is not a mock at all

Comment: Sure you really meant JPA? I think this is about JAX-B.

Comment: @geoand could not add 
Mock with InjectMocks at the same time, but when I removed InjectMocks it works with only Mock.. howver at the end of all I just test with  thrown.expect(JAXBException.class); whether or not the real method throws an exception. So no need for the mock anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In your Method you get the `Marshaller` from a `JAXBContext`. To use your mock Marshaller, your need a JAXBContext that returns the mock when `createMarshaller` is called.

assuming the following class under test:

```
public class XmlMarshaller {
  private JAXBContextFactory contextFactory;

  public XmlMarshaller(JAXBContextFactory contextFactory) {
    this.contextFactory = contextFactory;
  }

  private JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> type) {
    return contextFactory.get(type);
  }

  public void toXml(Object obj){
    // ... your code
  }
}
```

your test setup would need to look like this:

```
public class XmlMarshallerTest {
  @Mock
  JAXBContext ctx;

  @Mock
  Marshaller marshaller;

  @Mock
  JAXBContextFactory factory;

  @InjectMocks
  XmlMarshaller classUnderTest;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); // creates mocks and injects the as needed into the classUnderTest

    when(ctx.createMarshaller()).thenReturn(marshaller);
  }

  @Test
  public void toXmlCallsJAXBMarshaller() {
    when(factory.get(SystemPointDto.class)).thenReturn(ctx);
    SystemPointDto systemPointDto = new SystemPointDto();

    classUnderTest.toXml(systemPointDto);

    verify(marshaller).marshal(eq(systemPointDto), any(ByteArrayOutputStream.class));
  }
}
```